# How to create a steady 5V battery driven supply for ESP32, with huge intermittent power spikes through other step-up circuit?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, battery-operated, transient, spike

Do I really need two batteries? I am having huge trouble keeping the 5 V power supply for the ESP32 microprocessor stable, while *the other booster* draws maximum power in pulses. **The 5 V buck converter output then spikes between 3-8 V**.

I'm constructing a DIY portable PEMF device functionally similar to the "ICES C5" device.

The principle is fairly easy to explain: **A battery (3S LiPo 11-12 V) drives a [5V buck converter module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003233744394.html) that powers an ESP32 board, with an onboard 3.3 V regulator**. This is the sensitive part.

The ESP controls the power circuit, which consists of a **boost buck converter** (cheap 1 A 400 kHz [XL6009E1](https://www.nikom.biz/pdf/XL6009.pdf) module), that **charges a 6700 µF capacitor to between 16 and 35 V** (software adjustable) and goes on to feed a MOSFET H-bridge that powers some coils. The coils are around 1.1 Ω each, and the device may at most drive 12 of them at a time in parallel, for a period of 100 µs, at max 16 pulses per second. The maximum average power draw from the power circuit is then <300 mA at 12 V.
The H-bridge itself (HIP4081) gets its power directly from the battery and is specified for (abs max) 10.5 - 16 V.

As initially mentioned, keeping the ICs happy during pulsing proved to be very hard. When a pulse starts, the current ramps up from 0 to about 10-15 A per coil over 100 µs, totaling **estimated max 150 A**. As the capacitor voltage falls, the booster starts increasing its output. This draws so much power, that *the 5 V regulator gets much less than 12 V for a short while*. Its output is very far from 5 V, occasionally spiking down to 3 V, and then up to 8 V before settling again on 5V, which causes brown-outs and surely a number of other phenomena. This occurs more frequently as the battery drops below 50 %. The 3.3 V onboard regulator appears unable to cope, and spikes are seen on every TTL test point.

The capacitor charging is regulated partly through the Enable (EN) pin on the booster, and partly through adjusting the booster feedback voltage V<sub>fb</sub> with a DAC pin. This means, that **the booster can be turned on and off on demand**, and **the voltage can *initially* be slowly ramped up** to its desired value in order to reduce load as the capacitor charges.
***So startup is not a problem - pulsing is***.

The ESP32 draws avg 70 mA (20 mA in light sleep).
**How can I create a steady power supply for the ESP32, given the huge power demand of the parallel pulsing circuit?**

**What (I think) I have already tried that didn't reduce the spikes:**

- Placing a 1000 µF capacitor across the booster input.
- Placing a 0.1 as well as a 1000 µF capacitor across the 5 V output.
- Placing a diode in series with the 5 V converter input (+), followed by a 1000 µF capacitor to (-).
- Using the LiPo balancer cable output for the 5 V converter, and the thick main cables for the booster.
- (possibly) Using a linear 5 V regulator instead of the buck converter.

**What I've tried that DID reduce the spikes:**

- *Using a separate battery* for the ESP32. This very effectively solves the problem, but with the extra bulk.

**What I did not yet try:**

- Capacitors on the onboard 3.3 V regulator.
- Other voltage regulators
- Modulating the booster during pulsing
- Ask on stackexchange :)

**Update**

My assumption was wrong, that the booster was somehow creating the large spikes. There were several issues that combined led to that misunderstanding:

- My 4 channel oscilloscope has common ground. When I measure a high voltage point at the same time as a TTL point on the ESP32, the TTL point shows on the order of 10 times larger interference in comparison to when I remove the HV test point. Additionally, measuring HV and LV point simultaneously worsens the functioning (oscillation) or makes it stop working. This behaviour led me to believe that there were extreme spikes on the 5V and 3.3V side, when in fact, they both seem to be more in the order of **+/-0.6V when measured in isolation at the ESP32 supply/gnd and output pins**.
- There are indeed spikes when the pulse starts (capacitor starts discharging through the H-bridge), but **the biggest spike on the supply is when the pulse stops** (capacitor discharge is cut at its peak ~150 A) and the H-bridge is disabled.
- It appears that the fluctuation was amplified by the attempt to control voltage DAC1 via resistor to V<sub>fb</sub> on the booster. I assume that during a spike, the DAC1 also output fluctuates, and thereby jogging the sensitive 1.25 reference feedback voltage.
- The 12V 10K pullup on H-Bridge enable (EN) was too slow to return to high after a pulse, so during the return to high, when the H-bridge eventually cut the current, the EN voltage jolted down, causing it to oscillate for some time on every pulse.

**Solution**

- Part 1: Cut the DAC1 to V<sub>fb</sub> line and use an external potentiometer for voltage control instead.
- Part 2: Use a 1K pullup instead of 10K to the H-Bridge enable (EN) pin.

I have since been able to run the battery down to 5% / 11 V on full load with no brownouts.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Voltage converters]
[image: Build]

Comment: What 5V buck regulator are you using? Also schematic and layout would help.

Comment: I added a link to the 5V regulator, schematic and picture of the build and regulators. Let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Comment: I'd suspect common impedance coupling in the wires, if high current flows in GND wire then "0V" is no longer "0V"

Comment: _"The output then spikes between 3-8V."_ Which output?

Comment: @bobflux This sounds reasonable, although I seem to remember having tested connecting 5 V buck converter to the LiPo balancer cable, which should reduce that effect if I understand correctly.

Comment: @winny I clarified, meaning the 5 V buck converter output.

Comment: Sounds like you need either (a) a big battery that can supply all the current the booster is trying to take, or (b) a booster that takes less current and charges the capacitor more slowly. Adding a maximum current limit to a booster circuit isn't impossible but since this is a pre-built module you'd have to do some reverse engineering first.

Comment: If you can, use a battery with even more cells?  High enough voltage and it's buck converters all around.

Comment: Please show input and output voltage in an oscillogram in the 3 and 8 V cases.

Comment: Do you have a 2nd GND path between the ESP board and the H-Bridge? This shoud be avoided.

Comment: I added update and solution above. The problem wasn't what I thought, so the question is in fact misleading.